# How to performSegue or go to another view from a cell when the superclass of the main class is UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview, swift5

I have a class which is a type of `UICollectionViewCell`.
In this class, I have another `CollectionView` which when I select a cell of this inner collection view, I go to another view or perform a segue. I really need some help with it as The class is `CollectionViewCell` and `performSegue()` is not working.

```
class MyGamesController: UICollectionViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


      // performSegue is not working here


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you looking for by using swift protocols read more [HERE](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html)

First you need to know that `performSegue()` works on `UIViewController`

You need to create a protocol for your `collectionViewCell` , I guess here is `MyGamesController` like this:

```
protocol MyGamesControllerDelegate {
func insidCellDidSelect()
}
```

And add an instance of it to your class:

```
var delegate : MyGamesControllerDelegate?
```

Now when you call `delegate?.insidCellDidSelect` in your `MyGamesController` 's `didSelectItemAt` you can trigger it inside your parent VC by doing steps below:

When you are creating an instance of `MyGamesController` i.e in`cellForItemAt` attach the cells delegate to the parent `ViewController` which is creating it like this:

```
   class TheVCYouWantToPerformSegue : MyGamesControllerDelegate {
   ...

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = ... as! MyGamesController
    cell.delegate = self
```

Then you can implement the protocols method inside your VC body and get notified :

```
func insidCellDidSelect() {
//Perform Segue goes here
}
```

Comment: and did that and it works if i tried to print anything, but when i perfromSegue it says Receiver (<KooraQ.homeTappedViewController: 0x7f9b22f73740>) has no segue with identifier 'test'' although there is a segue by that identifier

Comment: I'm glad that I could help :) 
Are you sure you have the segue with exact name? can you please share some screen shots from your  storyboard where you named the segue?

Comment: it worked with some other delegate but the way you did works too thank you so much man :D